# div not being selected when pound sign is appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For debugging purposes, this is what I tried to type in Chrome Console:

```
$("#loading")
>  null
```

But if I do this, it correctly retrieves the div:

```
$("loading")
>  <div id="loading" align="center" style="display: none;">
```

I'm using jquery-1.4.1.min.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

This doesn't make sense to me, why can I not select a div by # sign but I can when I exclude it?

Edit: Sorry, huge fail on my part. I meant the other way around. Please see the revised question.

[image]

The only other js library i have is prototype.js, which is loaded after jquery script.

Comment: If you don't put a `#` it looks for a class called `loading`. Edit: Not a class, per [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @boj You need to put dot infront of classname to look for a class in jquery `$('.loading')` will look for class called **loading**.

Comment: @JustinJohn Yes, I edited my comment to reflect that. What would it look for if you left out the `.`?

Comment: @boj It will return an empty array as not match will be happen.

Comment: See Edit. I wrote the question in reverse.

Comment: Do you have other JS libraries loaded onto the page that might reassign the value of `$`?

Comment: I have prototype.js, the latest version. Does that cause any issue?

Comment: Not sure if any are specific to your situation, but a Google search on `prototype and jquery conflicts` comes up with a number of forum/wiki posts. jQuery is always exposed via the `jQuery` variable, though, so try your same search for `'loading'` and `'#loading'` with `jQuery` instead of `$` and see if you get the same results.

Comment: @ajp15243 WTF... that was it... dumb prototype.js was overriding $ sign -_- Thank you, I'd accept your answer if you posted one. Edit: Oh you did.

Comment: @l46kok I also edited it with a brief description of the library conflicts, along with some doc links. It is unfortunate that libraries conflict over `$` :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [jQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Some basic rules when using jQuery selectors follow (these are by no means exhaustive, you should look at the docs):

- Using a `#` at the beginning of your selector will search for all DOM nodes with an `id` of whatever word follows the `#`. So `$('#loading')` will select DOM nodes with `id="loading"`. This should only return one element, since non-unique `id`s on a page are invalid HTML.
- Using a `.` at the beginning of your selector will do a similar search to `#`, but will look at all DOM nodes' `class` attributes instead and select those with a class matching your selector. So `('.loading')` will select DOM nodes with `loading` in their `class` attribute's value.
- Using simply a word with no preceding symbols will attempt to select all DOM nodes whose element tag name matches your selector's word. So `$('loading')` will attempt to find all `<loading>` tags, but since this isn't an actual HTML tag, nothing will be selected.

**EDIT**
So while the above is true, it seems that you had conflicts between prototype.js and jQuery. These are well known and much lamented. You can look at jQuery's [wiki entry on using jQuery with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) and the documentation on [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for more information on this. Essentially, you will need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` to access the jQuery library.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#loading")` indicates to get dom with specific `id` for that `#` sign is used.

without `#` jQuery will not recognize `dom with id`.

Similarly to get specific `DOM` with `class` name you has to use `.`

**Some example selectors are :**

```
Selector        Example             Selects
  *              $("*")             All elements
  #id            $("#lastname")     The element with id="lastname"
.class           $(".intro")        All elements with class="intro"
.class,.class   $(".intro,.demo")   All elements with the class "intro" or "demo"
```

I have checked at my side and see the result.
[image]

Comment: That is PRECISELY why I am confused and asked this question. What you get in console should be the expected behavior, but it's not happening for me. I'm completely bewildered.

Comment: if jQuery does not allow us to select that way then how comes chrome console could..??

Comment: Chrome is being retarded perhaps...?? I am honestly not sure what's going on here or what could be causing that issue.

Comment: @l46kok no dude i have also tried it using jquery.1.4.1 js and its still working as per its nature...please try to clear cookies and cache and then try...

Answer (score 0):

`$("loading")` indicates that you are selecting an html element tag like `<div>` tag (`$('div')`).

`$("#loading")` indicates that you are selecting an html element tag with id like `<div id='loading'>`.

Have a look at jquery selectors... http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/