# jQuery won't find element by id, and won't recognize jQuery object

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1366924407" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1366924407" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1366924407" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js?1366924407" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1366924407" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1366924407" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1366924407" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="new_recipe_forms">
    <!--form stuff-->
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#new_recipe_forms').toggle()">New recipe</a>
```

I have several problems.

First, `$('#new_recipe_forms')` returns null instead of the div above.

Second, `$('new_recipe_forms')` returns the correct div, but doesn't respond to `.css("display")` in the console. The error is `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'css'`.

Comment: Show us your jQuery code and tell us what you want it to do, please.

Comment: `$ !== jQuery` on your page, you have a library conflict that you aren't telling us about. What other libraries are you using? If none, then you have a custom function named `$` defined somewhere on your page (which is relatively common for older native-js apps).

Comment: You sure that $ refers to jQuery? It looks like a shortcut for getElementById()

Comment: When do you call your function? Can you show us the code for it? Is it in a "ready" function?

Comment: @KevinB is probably right. `$('new_recipe_forms')` **without** the `#` shouldn't have selected the correct div, yet it did.

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery lib in your `<head/>`?

Comment: @tymeJV What does that have to do with the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're including both jQuery and PrototypeJS, you'll need jQuery's .noConflict()

Read this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
And this: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/

The dollar sign for both libraries work differently. Below is from jQuery's site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Or, for your case, an alternative is to consistently use `jQuery` instead of `$` when you intend to use the jQuery version of `$`.

I would do this instead if I have no other option and must include both libraries. It saves your own sanity.

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#new_recipe_forms').toggle()">New recipe</a>
```

Comment: Yup, question edit shows prototype being loaded (after jQuery), and I have helped someone before ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017617/div-not-being-selected-when-pound-sign-is-appended)) with this exact issue.